# PHP: Find all words starting with ":"

Tags: php, regex

Could you help me with PHP function/regex that in given text finds all words starting with character ":" ?

..in other words all substrings that start with ":" and are separated with " " (a space)

Comment: Ending with a space ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? (btw: the url isn't: `http://www.weWriteYourCode.com`)

Comment: Since when words end with space? I always thought that words cannot contain spaces. All life wrong...

Comment: Forien: oh you are right - space is used only as separator and is not including in word

Comment: Can it also be followed by a .!? or the end of the line?

Comment: What is allowed within the : and whitespace ? Only characters, only numbers, or ?

Comment: yes, it can be followed only by a whitespace or tab or end of line ...but not with any special symbol

Comment: "whitespace" or space? Whitespace has a special meaning in regex, that are all characters that are white! Spaces, tabs, newlines, ...

Comment: stema: aha, then whitespace should be the only right separator, i am sorry

Comment: @Michal `whitespace` is general name for all characters that are... let's say 'invisible'. That includes spaces, tabs, non-breaking spaces etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `:word` should probably be valid, and I guess `:word:another` should be considered two words, then you cannot say that there is always a space.

Words in natural languages can be followed by dots and other characters.
In digital input, they can be followed by end of line.

I suggest using this regexp:

`~:\w+~`

It takes any `:` character followed by at least one alpha character and will end at any character that is not valid letter.

Example: [on RegExr.com](http://regexr.com/3aga7)

You can also try `~:\w+\b~`, where `\b` is word boundary (literally end of word), but I see it not necessary here.

*Note: `\w` stands for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` meaning it catches underscores `_` and digits `0-9` as well. It works pretty much like variable/function naming in PHP*

---

### EDIT (some notes on usage):

You said that in given text (I understand that like input with random things) you want to extract all words prepended with `:`, for example `:word`. To do that easily, you should use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function with `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` flag.

Example:

```
$regex = '~(:\w+)~';
if (preg_match_all($regex, $input, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {
   foreach ($matches[1] as $word) {
      echo $word .'<br/>';
   }
}
```

Comment: You have a point about the `\b` character there. It's not really  necessary when used after `\w+`. If the text contains non-ASCII characters though, `\w` might be an issue. I'm not sure if it literally means `[A-za-z0-9_]`, or if it includes non-ASCII characters. - It might have to be more like `(:.+?)\b` if it doesn't, or perhaps use the Unicode classes: `(:\p{L})`

Comment: Unless we get some example input it's really hard to tell. Everything like encoding could be also matter of server configuration, I'm not sure. `\w` does not accept latin characters and I always use it as short for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. But I guess OP want to use it in similar way it works in `PDO` for prepared statemends, and there ASCII should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

regex: `/:\w+\s/g`

- \w Matchs any word character
- \s Matchs whitespace character

Comment: I would consider wrapping it in `\b` (word boundary) instead of using the white-space group, since he's looking for words.

Comment: Wrong. Words can end with dot `.`, exclamation mark `!` etc.

Comment: The `\b` class accounts for dots and exclamation marks. It matches any non-word character. - It's literally made for this situation.

Answer (score -2):

This would work:

```
preg_match('/^:\w*\s$/g', $var);
```

Comment: That finds *a word*, starting with `:` and ending in any number of spaces. Not even close to what was asked.

Comment: With any number of spaces ? Since when, please try this in a regex tester ;)

Comment: Ahh, yes. I misread the `*` position. Sorry about that :)
Doesn't change the main point though, you are only matching a single word, starting with a `:` and ending in a space.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, because I don't use PHP. But I suppose that your problem is that PHP would have reserved the character ":" for some reason in its regex implementation ?
Well, in that case, you still can catch any word beginning with ":" and ending with some space this way:

(...)

```
match('^\x3A[.]*[\s]');
```

("3A" is hexadecimal value for 58, which is the ASCII code for ":")

This should work, I think...

Comment: Using `[ ]` grouping for single character is waste of readability. `^` stands for beginning of input and OP didn't said if he wants to extract it only if it's the very first in input, but that he wants to extract all words within input. `:` is not reserved regex character unless in specific combination (like `(?:`)